# python function output writing to a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to create output files FileA and FileB which includes output from different function calls. Is it better to pass 'file' as argument to each of appropriate function and append to it? Or is there any other intelligent way to handle it? Thanks!

```
Output:
FileA contains OutA1, OutA2
FileB contains OutB1, OutB2

(python2.7)

def taskA1_func:
  <code>
  for lines in <code>:
    yield OutA1

def taskA2_func:
  <code>
  for lines in <code>:
    yield OutA2

def taskB1_func:
  <code>
  for lines in <code>:
    yield OutB1

def taskB2_func:
  <code>
  for lines in <code>:
    yield OutB2

write_to_file_func:
    creates file FileA and FileB

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Python 2.7 (or 3.1 respectively) you can use:

```
with open('FileA.txt', 'a') as FileA, open('FileB.txt', 'a') as FileB:
    FileA.write('something')
    FileB.write('something else')
```

Comment: Check your answer

Comment: That's better :D

Comment: Is this going to be part of "write_to_file_func" or writing happens under each task function? If it's former then output from each function is generator.How can I handle that?

Comment: Actually, you can deprecate `write_to_file_func()` and use my answer to replace the functionality